# Updated lualatex vs. tikz-feynman

Tags: luatex, tikz-feynman

**ORIGINAL QUESTION**: I have major problems compiling Feynman diagrams produced with the `tikz-feynman` package with `lualatex`. To make it less likely that I am just sloppy, I copied the example from this [nice answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/358196/121799).

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage[compat=1.1.0]{tikz-feynman}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{feynman}
    \diagram [vertical'=a to b, edges={red}] {
      i1 -- [fermion] a -- [fermion] f1,
      a -- [photon] b,
      i2 -- [fermion] b -- [fermion] f2,
    };

    \vertex [above right=of f1] (k1);
    \vertex [below right=of f1] (p1);
    \vertex [below right=of f2] (k2);
    \vertex [above right=of f2] (p2);

    \diagram* {
      (f1) -- [fermion] (k1),
      (f1) -- [photon] (p1),
      (f2) -- [fermion] (k2),
      (f2) -- [photon] (p2),
    };
  \end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Given that this the accepted answer, it is probably safe to assume that there was a time when this could be compiled. However, when I compile it on my updated TeXLive2018 distribution with `lualatex`, I get the error message

```
! Package pgf Error: Graph drawing library 'circular' not found.
```

**EXTRA INFORMATION**: This question was marked as a duplicate (by myself) of [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/453132/121799). Indeed, if one uses the [accepted answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/453157/121799) to fix it, one may arrive at

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{luacode}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphdrawing}

\begin{luacode*}
function pgf_lookup_and_require(name)
    local sep = package.config:sub(1,1)
    local function lookup(name)
        local sub = name:gsub('%.',sep)  
        if kpse.find_file(sub, 'lua') then
            require(name)
        elseif kpse.find_file(sub, 'clua') then
            collectgarbage('stop') 
            require(name)
            collectgarbage('restart')
        else
            return false
        end
        return true
    end
    return
        lookup('pgf.gd.' .. name .. '.library') or
        lookup('pgf.gd.' .. name) or
        lookup(name .. '.library') or
        lookup(name) 
end
\end{luacode*}

\usepackage[compat=1.1.0]{tikz-feynman}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{feynman}
    \diagram [vertical'=a to b, edges={red}] {
      i1 -- [fermion] a -- [fermion] f1,
      a -- [photon] b,
      i2 -- [fermion] b -- [fermion] f2,
    };

    \vertex [above right=of f1] (k1);
    \vertex [below right=of f1] (p1);
    \vertex [below right=of f2] (k2);
    \vertex [above right=of f2] (p2);

    \diagram* {
      (f1) -- [fermion] (k1),
      (f1) -- [photon] (p1),
      (f2) -- [fermion] (k2),
      (f2) -- [photon] (p2),
    };
  \end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The good news is that the error is gone. **However**, the output looks *really* different from the output of the original answer

[image]

in that the photon vertex on the top right has move to the left. When I marked my answer as a duplicate, I did not carefully check that the output is OK. Now I did, and realized that the output produced using Henri's fix produces unexpected results. Therefore, I'd like to reopen the question.

Comment: Workaround only.
Copy
`texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/graphdrawing/tex/pgflibrarygraphdrawing.code.tex` into the current direcroty and try the following:
change line 1093
        `if resolvers then`
to 
        `if false then`

Comment: There is already a question and also a pgf bug report about this.https://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/bugs/493/

Comment: The obvious solution is to use picture mode instead of tikz-pgf

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Yes, but as far as I can see this resolves the problem of the error. Yet there is a problem with that: after employing the fix, the output is quite different. (Of course, I am not 100% sure if these things are related, there could be a coincidental change of some library and this has nothing to do with the original problem. If that's not the case, I'd kindly ask you to help me reopening the question. As we both know: "It looks complicated because it is complicated." ;-)

Comment: @marmot The output is okay on my machine. Could you sent me a log-file?

Comment: @marmot In general people are quite able to find me ...

Comment: @UlrikeFischer People, yes, but marmots? (You got mail... ;-)

Comment: With version `1.09.0, Dev id: 6924 (lua 5.3 and pplib)`
different order is required to obtain correct output:
    `\diagram [vertical'=a to b, edges={red}] {`
      `a -- [photon] b,`
      `i2 -- [fermion] b -- [fermion] f2,`
      `i1 -- [fermion] a -- [fermion] f1,`
    `};`
With version `1.07.0, Dev id: 6686 (lua 5.2 and poppler)`
outputs are correct for original and changed order.

Comment: I have tested by changing from lua 5.3 to lua 5.2 in 1.09.0:
With version `1.09.0, Dev id: 6924 (lua 5.2 and pplib)`.
Then outputs are correct for original and changed orders.

Comment: I have tested by changing from lua 5.2 to lua 5.3 in 1.07.0:
With version `1.07.0, Dev id: 6686 (lua 5.3 and poppler)`.
Then output is correct for changed order, and it is incorrect
for the original order.

Comment: @AkiraKakuto These are all interesting observations but I think it is fair to say that they do not solve the fundamental problem. Or are you suggesting that for each diagram one should change the order for each version in a different way. Note also that different people seem to get different results.

Comment: @marmot: I'm only suggesting that the problem is caused by
differences of versions of used lua. I don't know
a solution.

Comment: I don't have time to check this right now, but it is possible that the underlying differences arise from different random seeds used in the graph drawing algorithms.  If that is indeed the case, I can release an update to TikZ-Feynman that sets a specific seed for all diagrams.  (Though such an update will be backward incompatible.)

Comment: @JP-Ellis: I replaced x by math.floor(x) in math.random in
SpringHu2006.lua to avoid argument error in lua 5.3. Was it bad?

Comment: @AkiraKakuto Well, it's not bad to have the seed changed (especially if it fixes another issue elsewhere), but it does mean the layout will (likely) change.

Comment: @JP-Ellis It is not the seed that changed but the whole RNG.  [Lua 5.2](https://www.lua.org/source/5.2/lmathlib.c.html#math_random) used the C standard library [`rand()`](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/ISO-Random.html#index-rand) function, whereas [Lua 5.3](https://www.lua.org/source/5.3/lmathlib.c.html#math_random) uses the POSIX [`random()`](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/BSD-Random.html#index-random) function.  Therefore you get entirely different random numbers even with the same seed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the latest [`master`](https://sourceforge.net/u/hmenke/pgf/ci/master/tree/) branch of my TikZ/PGF development repository it compiles fine, but thanks to new features in Lua 5.3 some graphs might appear mirrored.  There are [workarounds](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/468466/tikz-graphdrawing-differences-between-luatex-versions) for this but no backwards compatibility will be provided by TikZ.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{luacode}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphdrawing}

\usepackage[compat=1.1.0]{tikz-feynman}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{feynman}
    \diagram [vertical'=a to b, edges={red}] {
      i1 -- [fermion] a -- [fermion] f1,
      a -- [photon] b,
      i2 -- [fermion] b -- [fermion] f2,
    };

    \vertex [above right=of f1] (k1);
    \vertex [below right=of f1] (p1);
    \vertex [below right=of f2] (k2);
    \vertex [above right=of f2] (p2);

    \diagram* {
      (f1) -- [fermion] (k1),
      (f1) -- [photon] (p1),
      (f2) -- [fermion] (k2),
      (f2) -- [photon] (p2),
    };
  \end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The merge is pending https://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/git/merge-requests/14/ Unfortunately I still don't have access to the upstream repo.

Comment: I just merged it ;)

Comment: This also solves [my question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/467323/79060) (now flagged duplicate). Thanks. As you say "some graphs might appear mirrored", I wonder if there is already an example demonstrating this?

Comment: @JohannesZ https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/468466/tikz-graphdrawing-differences-between-luatex-versions