# tikz-feynman diagrams appear mirrored

Tags: tikz-pgf, luatex

It appears to be a well-known bug (see, e.g., [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/JP-Ellis/tikz-feynman/issues/73), [this one](https://github.com/CTeX-org/forum/issues/4), and the [overleaf article](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Feynman_diagrams)), but I still can't find a fix.

A simple diagram like that appears mirrored in the current version of LuaTeX locally ( pgf 3.1.9a,  LuaTeX, Version 1.15.0 (TeX Live 2022/Homebrew), Lua 5.4.4) as well as on overleaf:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{gensymb}



\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{tikz-feynman}
\title{Example}
\author{Evgenii Zheltonozhskii}

\begin{document}


 \maketitle

 \begin{align}
     \feynmandiagram [vertical=a to b] { i1 [particle=\(\nu_{\beta}\)] -- [fermion] a -- [fermion] f1 [particle=\(\beta\)], a -- [boson] b, };
 \end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]
[image: Expected result]

[This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/468467/93241) suggests that the problem is with random number generator in newer Lua versions but none of the proposed fixes worked for me.

Comment: Just use `vertical' = a to b`.