# How to manually modify label position in tikz-feynman

Tags: tikz-feynman

I am creating a diagram with tikz-feynman (code below) and two labels overlap each other. I would like to displace the two labels starting `$p - q ...` and `$p + q ...` so that they don't overlap. (I appreciate that I could just make the diagram bigger, but I want to locate it in a place where I have limited space.)

This code is compiled by LuaTex in lextlive 2018
https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Feynman_diagrams#Update_(9_November_2022)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}


\usepackage[compat=1.1.0]{tikz-feynman}
\usepackage{bm}

\begin{document}

\feynmandiagram [horizontal=a to b] {
  s0 [particle={$\omega_{\rm in}, \bm{k}_{\rm in}$}] -- [photon] i1 [label=above right:{$\bm{p}-\bm{q}, \omega-\Omega$}],
  s1 [particle={$\omega_{\rm out}, \bm{k}_{\rm out}$}] -- [photon] i2,
  i2 -- [charged scalar] i1,
  i1 -- [fermion] a -- [fermion, edge label={$\bm{p}, \omega$}] i2,
  a -- [gluon, edge label'={$\bm{q}, \Omega$}] b,
  f1 -- [fermion, edge label={$\bm{p}^\prime, \omega^\prime$}] b -- [fermion] f2,
  f1 -- [charged scalar] f2 [label=above left:{$\bm{p}^\prime+\bm{q}, \omega^\prime+\Omega$}],
  f1 -- [photon] l1 [particle={$\omega_{\rm out}, \bm{k}_{\rm out}$}],
  f2 -- [photon] l2 [particle={$\omega_{\rm in}, \bm{k}_{\rm in}$}],
};

\end{document}
```

[image: diagram]

Comment: I don't see the same thing as you do when I compile the document in LuaLaTeX in TeX Live 2023. Much of the text is positioned in different places when I compile it (though there still is overlap).

Comment: You are correct:
https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Feynman_diagrams#Update_(9_November_2022)

I will update this on the question.

Comment: Label is a special node. You can pass node options to a label through `label={[<options>]<angle>:<text>}`. For example with `label={[red,above right=10pt and -5pt]{$\bm{p}-\bm{q}, \omega-\Omega$}}` and `label={[blue,above left]{$\bm{p}^\prime+\bm{q}, \omega^\prime+\Omega$}}` the two labels are colored and don't overlap anymore. I don't have enough physics knowledge to decide which position is better. The different output between TeX Live 2018 and 2023 on Overleaf is probably caused by the different Lua version used by LuaTeX, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/468466.