# Rendering problem with TikZ Feynman

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-feynman, rendering

I would like to draw feynman diagrams with Tikz Feynman but I have some rendring problem :

Here the file with the first exemple of the documentation

```
\documentclass[11pt,french,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsfonts,babel,lmodern}
\usepackage[compat=1.0.0]{tikz-feynman}


\begin{document}

\feynmandiagram [horizontal=a to b] {
 i1 -- [fermion] a -- [fermion] i2,
 a -- [photon] b,
 f1 -- [fermion] b -- [fermion] f2,
};

\end{document}
```

And the rendering :

[image]

Which is not what I expect !

The expected result from the doc : 
[image: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/File:S-channel.png]

Any idea ? Thank You

Edit: Ok problem solve, TikZ Feynman need to be compile with LuaLatex (and I was compiling with pdflatex)

Comment: Does [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/468190/121799) help?

Comment: Not exactly but it make my try to compile with lulatex and it is now working.

I should have read few more sentences in the documentation :
"As a final remark, the calculation of where vertices should be placed is usually done through an algorithm written in Lua. As a result, LuaTeX is required in order to make use of these algorithms. If LuaTeX is not used, TikZ-Feynman will default to a more rudimentary algorithm and will warn the user instead. "

Comment: OK, I see. Yes, if you want to use the graph drawing routines, you need to compile with lualatex, which (as of now) prevents you from uploading the TeX file to the arXiv.

Comment: I think you should self-answer your question, pasting there your comment and the manual citation.

Comment: I will but I have to "wait 2 day for accepting my own answer" (maybe with more reputation I might be able to do it now but right now i can't ;) )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem solve.

Tikz need Lualatex for a proper rendering as explain in the documentation :

> "As a final remark, the calculation of where vertices should be placed
>   is usually done through an algorithm written in Lua. As a result,
>   LuaTeX is required in order to make use of these algorithms. If LuaTeX
>   is not used, TikZ-Feynman will default to a more rudimentary algorithm
>   and will warn the user instead. "

Comment: what if we have to compile our text with xelatex????